# Two tikzpictures side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to get these two `tikzpictures` to be shown side by side. This is what I have:

[image]

Not the most minimal example, but should be sufficient:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.33] %[x={10.0pt},y={10.0pt}]

\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (0,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (10,0) -- (10,10);

\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (3,5);

\draw[line width=2pt] (10,0) -- (13,5);

\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (3,15);

\draw[line width=2pt] (10,10) -- (13,15);

\draw[line width=2pt] (3,5) -- (13,5);

\draw[line width=2pt] (3,5) -- (3,15);

\draw[line width=2pt] (13,5) -- (13,15);

\draw[line width=2pt] (3,15) -- (13,15);

\draw[line width=1pt] (5,0) -- (5,10);

\draw[line width=1pt] (5,10) -- (8,15);

\draw[line width=1pt] (5,0) -- (8,5);

\draw[line width=1pt] (8,5) -- (8,15);

\draw[black, fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (5,0) -- (5,10) -- (8,15) -- (8,5) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture} % pic 1

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.33] %[x={10.0pt},y={10.0pt}]

\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (0,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (10,0) -- (10,10);

\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (3,5);

\draw[line width=2pt] (10,0) -- (13,5);

\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (3,15);

\draw[line width=2pt] (10,10) -- (13,15);

\draw[line width=2pt] (3,5) -- (13,5);

\draw[line width=2pt] (3,5) -- (3,15);

\draw[line width=2pt] (13,5) -- (13,15);

\draw[line width=2pt] (3,15) -- (13,15);

\draw[line  width=1pt] (0,10) -- (10,0);

\draw[line  width=1pt] (0,10) -- (3,5);

\draw[line  width=1pt] (3,5) -- (10,0);

\draw[black, fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (0,10) -- (10,0) -- (3,5) -- cycle;

\draw[line  width=1pt] (3,15) -- (10,10);

\draw[line  width=1pt] (3,15) -- (13,5);

\draw[line  width=1pt] (10,10) -- (13,5);

\draw[black, fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (3,15) -- (10,10) -- (13,5) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I've tried using `minipage` and `subfigure`/`subcaption` packages with no luck.

Edit: I'd like to have a caption below each tikzpicture (but I don't need to refer to it, so no external package is needed per se), hence why `minipage` is used, although now the spacing isn't consistent (too much space on the right):

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Delete the empty line between the minipages. It is like the `\par` command. Use instead:

```
[...]
\end{minipage}
%  no empty line here 
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
[...]
```

Comment: When using minipages this way, my diagrams overlapped and chomped captions to their last couple words. Can anything be done about that?

Comment: The two figures overlap if I use minipage. Do you have a suggestion about that?

Comment: then your figures are too big. Resize it with `\scalebox` or `\resizebox`

Comment: Why `.2\textwidth` instead of `.5\textwidth`? Could that be what caused the confusion?

Answer (score 48):

Why the minipages?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.33] %[x={10.0pt},y={10.0pt}]
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (0,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (10,0) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (3,5);
\draw[line width=2pt] (10,0) -- (13,5);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (3,15);
\draw[line width=2pt] (10,10) -- (13,15);
\draw[line width=2pt] (3,5) -- (13,5);
\draw[line width=2pt] (3,5) -- (3,15);
\draw[line width=2pt] (13,5) -- (13,15);
\draw[line width=2pt] (3,15) -- (13,15);
\draw[line width=1pt] (5,0) -- (5,10);
\draw[line width=1pt] (5,10) -- (8,15);
\draw[line width=1pt] (5,0) -- (8,5);
\draw[line width=1pt] (8,5) -- (8,15);
\draw[black, fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (5,0) -- (5,10) -- (8,15) -- (8,5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}% pic 1
\qquad % <----------------- SPACE BETWEEN PICTURES
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.33] %[x={10.0pt},y={10.0pt}]
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (0,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (10,0) -- (10,10);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (3,5);
\draw[line width=2pt] (10,0) -- (13,5);
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,10) -- (3,15);
\draw[line width=2pt] (10,10) -- (13,15);
\draw[line width=2pt] (3,5) -- (13,5);
\draw[line width=2pt] (3,5) -- (3,15);
\draw[line width=2pt] (13,5) -- (13,15);
\draw[line width=2pt] (3,15) -- (13,15);
\draw[line  width=1pt] (0,10) -- (10,0);
\draw[line  width=1pt] (0,10) -- (3,5);
\draw[line  width=1pt] (3,5) -- (10,0);
\draw[black, fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (0,10) -- (10,0) -- (3,5) -- cycle;
\draw[line  width=1pt] (3,15) -- (10,10);
\draw[line  width=1pt] (3,15) -- (13,5);
\draw[line  width=1pt] (10,10) -- (13,5);
\draw[black, fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (3,15) -- (10,10) -- (13,5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}% pic 2

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\qquad` you can have `\hspace{<length>}` (just remember the form

```
\end{tikzpicture}% NO SPACE!
\hspace{3cm}% NO SPACE!
\begin{tikzpicture}[...]
```

so you precisely control the horizontal space between the images. Vertical alignment can be obtained with TikZ methods (look for `baseline` in the manual).

Note also that the `a4` option is invalid, it should be `a4paper`.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to have a caption below each tikzpicture, but not necessarily made by a package (I don't need to refer to it).

Comment: By adding \vrule{} I was able to introduce a line between the two pictures, but it was not centered. Do you know offhand how to fix this?

Comment: (I hacked it by adding an extra blank column to one of the diagrams)

Comment: @rschwieb `\qquad\vrule\qquad` should do

Comment: @egreg, Can you help me with another issue ? Often, when I place a Figure (tikz) in a proof of a Theorem, I see that after compiling the latex, the Figure is placed in another place (before or after the theorem) where I don't want. So how exactly place a Figure exactly in some where in the proof of a Theorem ? Thanks

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR You don’t want to use `figure`

Comment: @egreg, I mean I want to place a Figure in a proof of a Theorem in a `particular` place (e.g., after a particular line). But in most cases the figure is `automatically` adjusted in `arbitrary` place rather than in between the Proof.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR You use `figure` if you need a caption and then there’s no problem in letting the object to float. Just use ‘center’ or even `\[...\]`

Comment: @egreg, Thank you very much. Now if I have two side-by-side figures and I need to give two different captions. How do we do that ? For example, in your above nice answer, you placed two figures side-by-side through command `\qquad`. How do we write two different `captions` below each figure ? Any Help please

Comment: can we have `(a) ` `(b)` below of each image respectively?

Comment: @alper `\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}\begin{tikzpicture}<first>\end{tikzpicture} & \begin{tikzpicture}<second>\end{tikzpicture} \\ (a) & (b) \end{tabular}`

Comment: When we use `figure` can we keep the figures centered like using in `\begin{center}`?

Comment: @alper Replace `\begin{center}` with `\begin{figure}[htp]\centering` (and of course `\end{center}` with `\end{figure}`).

Answer (score 13):

Here is another version:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={inner sep=2pt,fill,outer sep=0,circle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,line width=1pt]
 \coordinate (1) at (0,0,0);
 \coordinate (2) at (0,1,0);
 \coordinate (3) at (1,1,0);
 \coordinate (4) at (1,0,0);
 \coordinate (5) at (0,0,1);
 \coordinate (6) at (0,1,1);
 \coordinate (7) at (1,1,1);
 \coordinate (8) at (1,0,1);
 \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}{
     \node[mynode] at (\x) {};
 }
 \draw (1) -- (2) -- (3) -- (4) -- cycle;
 \draw (5) -- (6) -- (7) -- (8) -- cycle;
 \draw (1) -- (5)  (2) -- (6) (3) -- (7) (4) -- (8);
 \draw[thin,fill=blue!50,opacity=0.5] (0.5,0,0) -- (0.5,0,1) -- (0.5,1,1) -- (0.5,1,0) --cycle;
 \node at (0.5,-0.2,1) {(\textit{h\,k\,l})};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,line width=1pt]
 \coordinate (1) at (0,0,0);
 \coordinate (2) at (0,1,0);
 \coordinate (3) at (1,1,0);
 \coordinate (4) at (1,0,0);
 \coordinate (5) at (0,0,1);
 \coordinate (6) at (0,1,1);
 \coordinate (7) at (1,1,1);
 \coordinate (8) at (1,0,1);
 \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}{
     \node[mynode] at (\x) {};
 }
 \draw (1) -- (2) -- (3) -- (4) -- cycle;
 \draw (5) -- (6) -- (7) -- (8) -- cycle;
 \draw (1) -- (5)  (2) -- (6) (3) -- (7) (4) -- (8);
 \draw[thin,fill=blue!50,opacity=0.5] (1) -- (8) -- (6) --cycle;
 \draw[thin,fill=blue!50,opacity=0.5] (2) -- (4) -- (7) --cycle;
 \node at (0.5,-0.2,1) {(\textit{h\,k\,l})};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can reduce the `\coordinate` definition bit by

```
 \foreach \x/\y/\z/\a in {0/0/0/1,0/1/0/2,1/1/0/3,1/0/0/4,0/0/1/5,0/1/1/6,1/1/1/7,1/0/1/8} {
    \coordinate (\a) at (\x,\y,\z);
    }
```

if you want.

Comment: Can we use `figure` instead of `\end{center}` while keeping it centered?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  But I believe that in some cases you need to add `%` after each node command.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, fill=cyan!40, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm]{Ti\textit{k}Z};
\hspace{3cm}
\node[draw, fill=red, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text=white]{Ti\textit{k}Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/228228)