# Two tikz pictures and position of the caption

Tags: tikz-pgf

With the following codes

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, 
text width=7em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse, node distance=4.5cm,
minimum height=2.5em] 

\begin{figure} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm,auto]

\node [block] (firm) {Bob's favorite $i$};
\node [cloud, right of= firm] (C) {country $A$};
\node [cloud, below right of=firm] (C') {Alice $B$};

\path [line, thick] (firm) -- node {t}(C');
\path [line, thick] (C') -- node {t}(C);
\path [line,dashed, very thick] (firm) --  node {t+1}(C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}% NO SPACE!
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm,auto]

\node [block] (firm) {Bob's favorite $i$};
\node [cloud, right of= firm] (C) {country $A$};
\node [cloud, below right of=firm] (C') {Alice $B$};

\path [line, thick] (firm) -- node {t}(C');
\path [line, thick] (C') -- node {t}(C);
\path [line,dashed, very thick] (firm) --  node {t+1}(C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Bob and Alice}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have 
[image]

> How can I  make the figure in the center?

---

I have the following problems:

- If I use `\centering` in the `figure` environment, the two pictures would be in two rows; but I want to keep them side by side.
- **I have tried to rescale the picture like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213080/5590) does. But I don't know where to put the scaling parameters in my case.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two tikzpictures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213075/two-tikzpictures-side-by-side)

Comment: No. One can see that this is *not* a duplicate if one reads carefully what troubles I have. I have already mentioned explicitly in the post that the linked question is indeed related but answers there do not apply directly to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since images are relatively simple, I suggest to redraw them. In this use new syntax for positioning and style definition. In redrawing you actually need to change only some parameters, which will shrink image width:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, 
                calc, % added
                intersections, positioning, shapes}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ % changed from tikzstyle
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners,
                text width=4em, % reduced, now text is in two lines
                minimum height=3em, align=center},
 line/.style = {draw, thick, -latex'},
cloud/.style = {draw, ellipse, minimum height=2.5em, inner xsep=0pt}
        }

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2cm and 1.5cm, % changed (reduced)
        auto]
\node [block] (firm) {Bob's favorite $i$};
\node [cloud, right=of firm] (C) {country $A$}; % new syntax according to positioning library
\node [cloud, below=of $(firm)!0.5!(C)$] (C') {Alice $B$}; % use of calc library

\path [line] (firm) -- node {t}(C');
\path [line] (C') -- node {t}(C);
\path [line,dashed, very thick] (firm) --  node {t+1} (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfil % for distance between images
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2cm and 1.5cm,
        auto]
\node [block] (firm) {Bob's favorite $i$};
\node [cloud, right=of firm] (C) {country $A$};
\node [cloud, below=of $(firm)!0.5!(C)$] (C') {Alice $B$};

\path [line] (firm) -- node {t}(C');
\path [line] (C') -- node {t}(C);
\path [line,dashed, very thick] (firm) --  node {t+1} (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Bob and Alice}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Default text width of `article` is very narrow. Journals or conferences usually have margin much more narrow, less then 25 mm. In this case you can use wide `block`, for example as you have in your MWE (7em).